# I have two radio buttons, both the radio buttons are checked by default in safari browser

Tags: button, safari, radio-button, default, selected

[Both the radio buttons are selected by default on safari browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tEcYs.png) Other browsers only show one button as selected.

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="pure-radiobutton ownerradio">
        <input id="radio1" name="radio1" type="radio" class="radio" value="1">
        <label for="radio1" style="color:#333;">Same as Owner</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <div class="pure-radiobutton ownerradio ownerradio2">
        <input id="radio2" name="radio2" type="radio" class="" value="2"> 
        <label for="radio2" style="color:#333;">Same as Manager</label> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do they have the same name? Share your html.

Comment: Please share your code, and read the part of this page on radio buttons: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Comment: <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="pure-radiobutton ownerradio">
       <input id="radio1" name="radio1" type="radio" class="radio" value="1">
       <label for="radio1" style="color:#333;">Same as Owner</label>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
      <div class="pure-radiobutton ownerradio ownerradio2">
       <input id="radio2" name="radio2" type="radio" class="" value="2">
       <label for="radio2" style="color:#333;">Same as Manager</label>
      </div>
     </div>

Comment: It is displayed correctly on all other browsers except safari.Is safari the most used browser in US?